# What is the minimum tech level for manned flight?

Tags: hard-science, technological-development, flight

For instance, a hot air balloon is really pretty simple; I suspect that even thousands of years ago, it would have been possible to make - steam engines existed in 1AD, after all.

So, just how far back can you go, and still have the tech available to carry a human hundreds of feet into the air? *Could* the romans have made one? How about the stone age cavedwellers? Once you can tan skin, you can make a balloon, and hot air just needs a fire...

But what about **directed** flight? Balloons just drift; how much more technology do you need to build something that will push you through the air, in the direction you want to go? Have an ancient civilisations built such a thing, or even the components needed to do so?

Comment: 1AD? Can I have a source on that?

Comment: Technology and the application of that technology are different.  I'm guessing you've heard *"necessity is the mother of invention"* It makes sense for a lot of reasons, if you don't have a need to fly, you're not going to figure out how to do so.  You seem to already know what technology is required, tanning, ropes, heat and a way to bring them together.  Those techs have existed for a really really long time...there was no need for flight nor was there an understanding that the techs could be used to fly...that all comes with time and scientific understanding.

Comment: I don’t suppose throwing a *man* off a hundred foot tall cliff counts? Or the story of Icarus??

Comment: Can you put some minimum limits on the amount of control or airspeed needed?  With a large folding fan and no wind, a caveman could control their direction of movement in a hot air balloon - it just wouldn't be very fast

Comment: I'm VTCing as too broad because it's something we're not really supposed to have on SE generally : an open ended discussion type question.

Comment: @Punintended Sorry, I'm not really sure what kinds of quantities would be meaningful here - my intention is, for the flight to be an actual, viable means of transport, so I guess they have to be either faster or less (personal) energy cost than just walking, but I don't know how that translates into specific quantities of control or airspeed?

Comment: @StephenG Could you suggest how I could improve it? I thought I had been quite specific and non-opinion-based, but I guess not; how can I do better?

Comment: @James it's not enough to have the physical items, you also have to have the tools to assemble them to sufficient tolerance, as well as the scientific understanding to know that such an assembly is possible. Like, cavemen had access to iron ore and fire, but could they make steel? No, because they didn't know how to put them together in the right way.

Comment: @Benubird That was exactly my point.

Comment: One problem here is that if you look at all the questions you ask in that post.  There are five or six individual questions here, any one of which would be more than enough food for thought for *one* post on WB SE.  I get the impression you don't have a very specific time period or scenario in mind and that makes this too broad for WB.  Remember - you can make other posts for other specifics and that format is better suited to SE in general (IMO) than these multi-question posts.  I would suggest focusing on one single era and technology, as narrow as you can per post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this for being _unclear what you're asking_. You want to know what the minimum technology level is, then state it in the question. What are you actually asking for?

Comment: "How early in our time line could tech X have been implemented?" is a regular question here. Such questions are difficult to answer because "X" *did not* happen, which suggests it *could not* happen. Obviously something could occur a few years earlier, but decades? Centuries? Millennia? Any tech stands atop a pyramid of experience, education, and innovation, and you're asking how far back along that mountain the tech could have occurred. Regrettably, it's very hard to know without understanding even the politics and sociology during the path of development. Do you have a specific time in mind?

Comment: Re the `hard-science` tag be aware that using that flag moves your question from "suggest plausible" to "prove scientifically" and for your questions it's totally inappropriate as a tag.